Google maps ios marker location issues
I am using google maps in ios. Every thing is working fine in simulator and device but when I search address using placeclient and select it then marker place a different location.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXWF4cs29CfQ_jyPordo3axa1yXjXCux/view?usp=sharing
Above is the video link.
I am using the below code to put marker
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 20)
                self.gmsMapView.animate(to: camera)
                self.gmsMapView.camera = camera
                self.currentMarker.position =  gmsMapView.camera.target


Can you show the logs for the coordinates received from the placeclient and the actual coordinates where the marker is placed?
